# Open android widget

Tags: java, android

I created an application that should open the android widgets screen and pick a specific widget.
I manage to open the widgets screen but can't pick a specific widget from the displayed list, this is the code I used:

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
    pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 1);
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0);
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
AppWidgetHost host = new AppWidgetHost(this, HOST_CODE);
host.startListening();
int nextId = host.allocateAppWidgetId();

Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
pickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, nextId);
startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);
```